# What is the proper way to check if a document in mongodb with find().limit()?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
for hashtag in hashtags: 
    existing_hashtag = hashtags_collection.find({"string": hashtag}).limit(1)
    if existing_hashtag:
        hashtags_collection.update({"string": hashtag}, 
                                   {"$inc": {"popularity": 1}})                                                      
    else:
        new_hashtag = {"string": hashtag,
                       "popularity": 1}
        hashtags_collection.insert_one(new_hashtag)
```

find_one will return actual object but I heard that it is not efficient. find + limit only returns a cursor object even if it doesn't find a match. So how can I implement find + limit in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't issue a query for each element in your *iterable* here "hashtags" instead, you should use the `$in` query operator.

That being said, you can use the `count` method to check whether or not any document in your collection "string"'s value is your array.

```
collection.count({"string": {"$in": hashtags}})
```

Last and not least, you don't need the `if/else` statement here, simply let MongoDB do the job for you by using bulk operation and the `upsert` option.

In conclusion you code should look like this.

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne


bulk_operations = [UpdateOne({'string': value}, {'$inc': {'popularity': 1 }}, upsert=True) 
                   for value in hashtags]  
hashtags_collection.bulk_write(bulk_operations)
```